# Polygon boundary from shapefiles not in latitude/longitude format

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, polygon, geopandas, latitude-longitude

I just downloaded the shapefiles for the County boundaries in Minnesota from [here][1].

Now I am expecting the boundaries of the Polygons/MultiPolygons to consist of latitude and longitudes (according to the metadata). Instead on loading the shapefiles I see huge numbers which don't seem like lat/long coordinates.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

If you look at the last column in the tables (within the images) I am unable to understand what those numbers represent and how I can convert them to latitudes and longitudes.

The .prj file contains:

> PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-93.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
> Is it possible to get the shape file for the county boundaries such that the locations are mentioned in latitude/longitudes?
> Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: The shapefile set likely includes a `.prj` -- Please [Edit] the Question to contain its contents **as text** (which is likely State Plane). By using images to show text, you obscure it from some devices and search engines.

Comment: @Vince I have added the .prj file thanks!

Comment: And so you've mostly answered your own Question -- the data must be reprojected from NAD83 UTM Zone 15 (technically, unprotected and possibly transformed) to the target geographic coordinate system. What have you tried?

Comment: @Vince I haven't tried transforming to state plane coordinates since the remaining part of my algorithm expects the boundaries to be in latitude/longitude coordinates. Is it possible to get the shape file for the county boundaries such that the locations are mentioned in latitude/longitudes? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, information about the CRS can be found in [the metadata file](https://resources.gisdata.mn.gov/pub/gdrs/data/pub/us_mn_state_dnr/bdry_counties_in_minnesota/metadata/metadata.html#Spatial_Reference_Information).

> Section 4: Coordinate System Horizontal Coordinate Scheme:    Universal
> Transverse Mercator
>
> UTM Zone Number:  15
>
> Horizontal Datum: NAD83
>
> Horizontal Units: meters
>
> Vertical Datum:   not applicable
>
> Vertical Units:   Not Applicable
>
> Depth Datum:  not applicable
>
> Depth Units:  Not Applicable

As well as when reading the shapefile with GeoPandas, one can get the [EPSG:26915](https://epsg.org/crs_26915/NAD83-UTM-zone-15N.html?sessionkey=1k0zqbkgzd).

```py
import geopandas as gpd

zipfile = 'D:/TESTING/shp_bdry_counties_in_minnesota.zip!mn_county_boundaries_500.shp'
# url = 'https://resources.gisdata.mn.gov/pub/gdrs/data/pub/us_mn_state_dnr/bdry_counties_in_minnesota/shp_bdry_counties_in_minnesota.zip'

gdf = gpd.read_file(zipfile)

print(gdf.crs) #epsg:26915
```

And then reproject with [`gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs) if needed.